# How can i access the microphone in an apk made with kivymd

Tags: python, android, kivymd, pyaudio, buildozer

I am currently programming an app in python with kivymd that uses the SpeechRecognition library. The app should start the speech recognition after a button is pressed and everything works fine when i execute the code in pycharm. However when i press the button on my mobile device (android enviroment) it raises the unknown value error instantly.

Things that i tried in the buildozer.spec file are:

`requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,android`

Things that i tried in python are:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
if platform == 'android':
  request_permissions([Permission.RECORD_AUDIO])
```

I hope you can help me solve this issue while still using the SpeechRecognition library.

Comment: You can develop an API for server in order to use SpeechRecognition and record the sound on mobile if supported and send it to the server with requests. You will have the recognition and hopefully it fixes your problem